# Anybody have luck Scanning from HP OfficeJet Pro 8600 to Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scanning, hp-officejet

Having no issues printing to HP OfficeJet Pro 8600 from Ubuntu.  Ubuntu found network printer and installed ok using closest driver "OfficeJet 8500".

However, scanner was not detected.  I was wondering if anybody had luck with scanning in Linux from that particular device.

Answer (score 2):

You need a recent [hplip](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html) driver to enable scanning and proper A4/Letter detection for any HP multifunction driver.
They print with some driver sometimes, and scan with some scanjet driver at limited resolution, but hplip enables full proper functionality.

Comment: I have an HP L7680 and xsane (scanner app) works great with it. I use the hplip driver.

Comment: hplip includes (compilable) sane backend and a cups printer driver...